# unix command is executing before the authentication completed over SSH

Tags: unix, batch-file, ssh

i try to open a Unix session through java code and windows using putty.exe as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /B C:/scripts/Session.bat ");
```

the 'Session.bat' file content is:

```
putty.exe -t -ssh root@aaa -pw abcd -P 22
```

**aaa** is the server name.
**root** is the user name.
**abcd** is the password

Now, the session opens well, but i want to run couple of simple commands from the above command (ll -s, pwd, etc.).
But when i try to add txt file which contains these commands to the above command, i see that the commands are executing after the user name entered and before the password.
the complete command is:

```
putty.exe -t -ssh root@aaa -pw abcd -P 22 -m C:\scripts\commands.txt
```

that's why i get the error (below) since the command "ll" came before the password:

```
Using username "root".

bash: ll:: command not found
```

please help me...
Thanks

Comment: I guess it is just because `ll` is an alias that `root` does not have. What if you have `ls` instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way the command could execute on the remote computer before the password is processed. Surely an alias is missing in root's bash startup files.

Try adding `alias ll='ls -l'` to /root/.bash_profile ?

Comment: I guess it should be `ls -l` (Long list)

Comment: Indeed. Corrected. Thx.

Comment: @user1630359 Run the actual command you want to run; don't rely on an alias.